# WSO2 api manager configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using wso2-am 2.
I have enabled analytics (from api-manager.xml) and modified DASServerURL to use port 7714 instead of 7712.
But I'm getting theses exception:
**org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)**

It look like it is still using the old port 7712?
 A second question, I know that the api manager is persisting the configuration in it's database, so my question is: if i modify for example api-manager.xml, will it update the new setting in the DB or how to force this update?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to change port settings in two places.

1. `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml`
2. `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j.properties` only if you have added `DAS_AGENT` to `log4j.rootLogger`

By default analytics distribution port offset set to 1 in carbon.xml. But it seems you have set it to 3. Make sure to change the port in above two places.

The answer to your second question is, API-M persist API data in the database. There are certain server configurations such as user data, registry data persisted in the database. But above configuration is not persisted and if you changed it, you have to restart the server to effect that.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Thanks Sampath.
I didn't edit the log4j.propertes.
So, is this exception thrown by the DAS_LOGGER ?
 And why even when disabling the analytics component i still get this exception?
Last question, I didn't find a clear explanantion about this DAS_agent,why is it used?

Answer (score 0):

1.if your DAS offset is 3. You should set the tcp port is 7614 and restart your APIM. your 7612 is configed in apim, cannot change on admin-dashboard.

2.when you change the *.properties or *.xml.I suggest you restart your app.